# Update from linked server (mysql) to local sql database.

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a way to setup a scheduled update from a linked server I created to a local db, I am not familiar with triggers but from what I've read you have to set them up on the originating server, and I only have read access to the mysql Database.  Basically all that I am trying to do is make a local copy of two tables from the mysql db.  I can manually do so with select into statements, but I would like to have some automation if possible.  Any thoughts on how to achieve this? Also I am using SQL server 2008 R2. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options to do:

- Copy all data from the source table (do not use this if the source table is big)
- If you have a column in the source table which can be used to determine which records should be copied, use that (this is mostly an auto updated timestamp column in MySQL)
- Set up a trigger to track modifications

To copy, you can set up a **[Linked Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx)** or you can use **[SSIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx)**

To use a linked server you can use **[OPENQUERY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx)**

You can schedule your task with **[SQL Server Agent](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx)**